# How do you replace the default webkit browser with another one in an android web view?

Tags: android, browser, uiwebview, webkit, webview

How can I change the webview in an app so it uses another engine, not the engine from the android browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "change the webview". If another browser elects to make its code available as a JAR exposing some sort of widget, you may be able to use that -- you would have to contact the browser developer to find out.

Comment: Thanks. I guess then if such a JAR doesn't exist for a certain browser, I'd have to get the source and make one myself.

Comment: @trusktr: Yes, assuming the source is publicly available and the code is organized in such a way that you could create such a custom widget.

Comment: Hmmmmm.... I debating whether I really should... But then again, WebGL for the Android browser will probably be out soon anyways.